# Populate dropdownlist inside a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a Dropdownlist in a Gridview and i have to show the records associated with every id.And the ID contains more than 10 records so how can i show them??

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                con.Open();
                var ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1");
                //int CountryId = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select LastName from Profile_Master",        con);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                con.Close();
                ddl.DataSource = ds;
                ddl.DataTextField = "LastName";
                ddl.DataBind();

            }
        }
```

Comment: did you try assigning `ddl.DataValueField` to some other column like ID?

Comment: No i dint assigned like that but what is the use??

Answer (score 0):

```
        FillSelect(myDropDownList, "--select--", "0", true);
        public static void FillSelect(DropDownList DropDown, string SelectItemText, string SelectItemValue, bool includeselectitem)
        {
            List<PhoneContact> obj_PhoneContactlist = getAll();

            if (obj_PhoneContactlist != null && obj_PhoneContactlist.Count > 0)
            {
                DropDown.DataTextField = "PhoneContactName";
                DropDown.DataValueField = "id";
                DropDown.DataSource = obj_PhoneContactlist.OrderBy(o => o.PhoneContactName);//linq statement
                DropDown.DataBind();

                if (includeselectitem)
                    DropDown.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(SelectItemText, SelectItemValue));
            }
        }
        public static List<PhoneContact> getAll()
        {

        obj_PhoneContactlist = new List<PhoneContact>();
        string QueryString;
        QueryString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Admin_raghuConnectionString1"].ToString();

        obj_SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(QueryString);

        obj_SqlCommand = new SqlCommand("spS_GetMyContacts");
        obj_SqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        obj_SqlConnection.Open();
        obj_SqlCommand.Connection = obj_SqlConnection;
        SqlDataReader obj_result = null;
        obj_SqlCommand.CommandText = "spS_GetMyContacts";
        obj_result = obj_SqlCommand.ExecuteReader();


        //here read the individual objects first and append them to the listobject so this we get all the rows in one list object

        using (obj_result)
        {
            while (obj_result.Read())
            {
                obj_PhoneContact = new PhoneContact();
                obj_PhoneContact.PhoneContactName = Convert.ToString(obj_result["PhoneContactName"]).TrimEnd();
                obj_PhoneContact.PhoneContactNumber = Convert.ToInt64(obj_result["PhoneContactNumber"]);
                obj_PhoneContact.id = Convert.ToInt64(obj_result["id"]);

                obj_PhoneContactlist.Add(obj_PhoneContact);
            }

        }

        return obj_PhoneContactlist;
        }
```

I have done this to get my phonecontacts which are in the data base into dropdown you can change the stored procedures and the values according to your need.

Hope this helps:D

Comment: But how to get the records associated with each ID??

Comment: you have to change it in the stored procedure, I used spS_GetMyContacts in that I used the statement to get all the contacts instead of that you have to get the values based upon the ID only a single statement changes

Comment: to get the values according to the id you can even send the present ID as one of the parameter and get the values according to the id

Comment: I am not using a stored proc for this and how can i fetch the records according to the user id??

Comment: You can change it from the command statement as per  your requirement

Comment: Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We just ran into this issue where I work.  Our way around this problem was to first get the DropDownLists UniqueID.  This is basically a Client ID.  Inside of that ID is a reference to the row of the GridView that it was selected from.  THE ONLY PROBLEM is that it seems to add 2 to the row count.  So if you select Row 1's DropdownList, the Unique ID will bring you a reference to the 3rd row. So:

Get the unique ID > Split it however you need to to get the row > use the row number to get the values you need.