# Populating Dropdownlist according to Firstname

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Populate dropdownlist inside a gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043557/populate-dropdownlist-inside-a-gridview)

I have a dropdownlist and i am populating it inside a gridview.In the first column i have Firstname and in the second column i have a DDL and i want to load the lastname associated with the firstname how can i achieve this??

```
Protected void GridView1_RowDataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            con.Open();
            var ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1");
            //int CountryId = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select FirstName,LastName from Profile_Master" , con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); 
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();
            ddl.DataSource = ds;
            ddl.DataTextField = "LastName";
            ddl.DataValueField = "FirstName";
            ddl.DataBind();


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {


            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {

 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=dbname;Integrated Security=True");

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select lastname from Profile_Master where firstname='" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text + "'", con);
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                System.Data.DataSet DS=new System.Data.DataSet();
                adp.Fill(DS);



                Control Ctr = e.Row.FindControl("ddl");

                DropDownList dd =  (DropDownList)  Ctr;
                dd.DataSource = DS;
                dd.DataTextField = "LastName";
                dd.DataValueField = "LastName";
                dd.DataBind();

}

}
```

Comment: When i do like this i am unable to load the DDL,the DDL is empty

Comment: Are you saying that you are unable to get data into ddl ? I have tested this code and its working. can you please post your code.

Comment: dd.DataSource = ds; here i am getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object error.

Unable to get the Data into the DDL

Comment: It means error is related to reference of ddl or dataset. 

1. Are you using new keyword for DS (DS=new DataSet()).

2. Do you have gridview with ddl name within template field of Gridview ?

one more thing you can remove con.open and con.close() from your code as you are using DataSet.

Comment: Ya i am using but the DDL is empty nothing is in the Dataset

Comment: Ya i have a ddl inside the gridview template field but the problem is with select statement as it is not fetching lastname into the dataset

Comment: I got your point. You just need to change  

  Control Ctr = e.Row.FindControl("ddl"); with 

   Control Ctr = e.Row.FindControl("DropDownlist1");

Comment: Even i have done that but the problem is with filling the dataset as it is null the DDL is empty

Comment: All right. What is understood that you dont have data against firstname so you are getting empty ddl. Am i correct ?

Comment: No i have data in firstname column and data in lastname column but the select statement in the above code is wrong, so dataset is empty and ddl is also empty.

Comment: hmmm. can you post your sql query only ?